PHP 8.2.7 compilation does not work when cURL is included
I get the following installing PHP on Alma Linux 8.10:
php-8.2.7/ext/curl/interface.c:3085: undefined reference to \`curl_easy_upkeep'

I thought this would be a common error (hence the post) and I have tried the following so far:

dnf install curl curl-devel
installed latest cURL to /usr/local/curl (can see lib and include directories)
tried several times including without curl in the configure command for PHP

So if anyone can beat me to it kudos to you.
For reference the full output of the error is:
lcrypto -lcrypt -lrt -o sapi/cli/php
ext/curl/interface.o: In function `zif_curl_upkeep':
/tmp/serverforge/downloads/php-8.2.7/ext/curl/interface.c:3085: undefined reference to `curl_easy_upkeep'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:310: sapi/cli/php] Error 1

I tried installing PHP from source (8.2.7) and I expected to have it install with cURL but only works without cURL in the php 8.7.2 configure command.
The full command I used was: ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php82 --enable-cli --enable-fpm --program-suffix=82 --with-xsl --with-libxml=/usr/local/libxml2 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --enable-bcmath --with-bz2=/usr/local/bzip2 --enable-calendar --with-curl=/usr/local/curl --enable-ftp --enable-gd --with-libdir=lib64 --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --enable-intl --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-xsl --enable-soap --enable-sockets; make; make install;
Note also, that /usr/local/curl/bin/curl --version outputs 8.8.0.
Note that both php74 and php80 compile fine. Can anybody understand what is happening here?
The cURL version is listed below, the libcurl that appears after is installed out of my control, so I do not know where to find it.
[root@localhost]# curl -V curl 8.8.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.8.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.4 OpenLDAP/2.4.46 Release-Date: 2024-05-22 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ipfs ipns ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd 
I changed the hard links for which curl-config to symlink to /usr/local/curl/bin/curl-config which changed the output but did not change the fact that it doesn't compile.
From looking at my system:
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.a
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.la
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4.7.0
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4.8.0
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.la
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.7.0

There are two installations it seems. How do I make it so the right installation is used? Currently --with-curl=/usr/local/curl is not doing it.
FYI:
[root@localhost]# curl-config --version
libcurl 8.8.0
[root@localhost]# curl-config --help
[root@localhost]# curl-config --static-libs
/usr/local/curl/lib/libcurl.a -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -llber -lzstd -lz -pthread
[root@localhost bin]# curl-config --ca
"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
[root@localhost]# curl-config --cc
gcc
[root@localhost]# curl-config --libs
-L/usr/local/curl/lib -lcurl
[root@localhost ~]# gcc -v
..
gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22) (GCC) 
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="AlmaLinux"
VERSION="8.10 (Cerulean Leopard)"
..


Add the OS (including the version) and release of GCC to the question.

Yep ok, done that. AlmaLinux v8.10 and gcc is 8.5.0.

If you have Alma Linux 8.10, then there is no need to compile php. PHP 8.2 is available in the repos.

With custom modules and so on?

To install PHP 8.2 in Alma Linux 8.10:
First, reset the PHP module (if necessary) and then enable PHP 8.2:
yum module reset php -y

yum module enable php:8.2 -y

You can then install PHP 8.2 and associated packages.
yum install php php-common php-cli -y

I just gave the basics for example but you can see them all with the following command:
yum list available | grep 'php.*[[:space:]]8.2'

